# How to create a Purchase Order record in Salesforce using CreateAsync method in c#

Tags: picklist, c#, force.com-toolkit-for-net

I'm a newbie to salesforce and i want to create a custom Purchase Order record using CreateAsync method of Force.com Tool.
I'm successfully able to create a record when i'm just passing the parameter value as string.

For e.g for a Campaign Creation :

```
var campRecord = new Campaign() { Name ="PickListCamp"};
```

The problem arises when i want to pass a pickup list value as a parameter in the CreateAsync method.

I'm getting the pickuplist values for say Status field of Purchase_Order object but when i pass the Pickup list value , i get an error saying :

> "Cannot deserialize instance of picklist from START_OBJECT value { or request may be missing a required field salesforce c#}".

I'm using the following piece of code to get the picklist values from Status column of Campaign object :

```
string dcampQry = "Select DurableId From FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName = 'Campaign' and DataType = 'Picklist' and DeveloperName = 'Status'";

var dcampResults = await client.QueryAsync<FieldDefination>(dcampQry);

var campDId = dcampResults.Records[0].DurableId;

string campQry = "SELECT DurableId, EntityParticleId, IsActive, IsDefaultValue, Label, ValidFor, Value  FROM PicklistValueInfo WHERE EntityParticleId = '" +campDId  + "'";

var campResults = await client.QueryAsync<Picklist>(campQry);

 Picklist campValue = campResults.Records[0];
```

After getting the pickuplist values, I'm passing the parameter as follows in the CreateAsync method :

```
var campRecord1 = new Campaign() { Name = "PickListCamp", Status = campValue };

var createdAccRecord1 = await client.CreateAsync("Campaign", campRecord1);
```

Can anyone help me out on how to create a record by passing a pickuplist value in CreateAsync method. I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Hi Srijesh, please include an example of the code you're using that *doesn't* work. I'm not a C# programmer, but it sounds like you're supplying the wrong type of value.

Comment: Hi David, I have updated the post with sample code. Kindly help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a C# developer, so I cannot tell you exactly what to write in your code, but I think it's clear that the cause is here:

```
var campRecord1 = new Campaign() { Name = "PickListCamp", Status = campValue };
```

`campValue` is an instance of a Tooling API object (`PicklistValueInfo`), representing the metadata for a single Picklist entry.

When you populate a picklist field, you don't supply an object - you supply a string value, the API name of the picklist entry. Here, you want the property `Value` from `campValue`, which should be a String.

The error you're getting back is indicating that Salesforce is receiving an object in its inbound REST request where a scalar value is expected.

Comment: Hi David,thank you for the response. Since the second parameter expects a pickuplist datatype,I passed campValue.  If I pass the Value property ,how should I pass the second parameter?

Comment: Srijesh, it's "picklist", not "pickuplist". A picklist value is a string, unless C# does something unusual with it.

Comment: Okay David ,I'll try that out and let you know as soon as possible. thanks

Comment: Hi David, 
 var campRecord1 = new Campaign() { Name = "PickListCamp", ? = campValue.Value };



Could you please suggest as to what the field name should be as 'Status' is of datatype Picklist.

I have defined the Campaign class as follows : 



 private class Campaign
        {
            public const String SObjectTypeName = "Campaign";

           
            public String Name { get; set; }
            public bool isActive { get; set; }

            public Picklist Status { get; set; }

        }

Comment: The Status field on Campaign is not an object. It is a string value. You're using the same class to represent the Tooling API result and the Campaign field value, and that will not work.

Comment: Got it thanks :)
So coming to the question of creating purchase order record, i'll pass all the picklist fields as string but any idea on how to pass the RecordType parameter

Comment: Record Type Id is also a String. Feel free to close this question and open a new one if you have further follow-up questions. You may wish to review the [SOAP API Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaign.htm) for details on field data types.